# Google search box only works 50% of the time

Tags: javascript, forms, search

I'm writing a new tab extension for Firefox, and I'd like to have a box that you can type in and have it search Google. I really don't want to use a custom Google search, just because I feel like it's inconsistent and seems cheap.

All that it's supposed to do is add your query to the end of the google URL (in the correct formatting, of course) and redirect you to that page. I have it working sometimes, but not all of the time.

Here's the code I have:

JS:

```
var textstring;

//Gets the text from the form
function getQ() {
    textstring = document.forms['Search'].elements[0].value;
}

//Does a Google Search
function googleSearch() {
    window.location ="http://www.google.com/search?q="+textstring;
}

//main function to run everything
function main() {
    getQ();
    googleSearch();
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="Search" >
<div id="test1">
    <input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div id="test2">
    <input type="button" value="Google Search" onclick="main();" />
</div>
</form>
```

Not sure why that last /form isn't showing up, but that's in there just so you guys know.

It works like 25% of the time. I can't figure out what's wrong with it. Could it just be that I'm testing it locally? I've been testing it in Firefox, but it seems to have the same issue in IE or Chrome, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just submit to google (*and avoid all the javascript*) ?

```
<form name="Search" method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" >
```

and use a normal submit button like

```
<input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
```

Since you have named the input element `q` and the method of the form is `get` it will create the correct url.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/gxun9/

Comment: Didn't know I could do that. Thanks! Works perfectly, and makes it sooo much easier. :)

Comment: ahh damn. looks like it's doing the same thing actually...don't know what's up with it :/